# Express - Unhandeled Promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, endpoint

I have two tables one for graduates and another for mentors. And I would like to find out which table an email is from using the following endpoint .

```
router.post("/reset/:email", async (req, res) => {

//search which table the email is from
const { email } = req.params;

try {
    const result_g = await pool.query(
        "select *  from graduates where email=$1",
        [email]
    );
    const result_m = await pool.query("select *  from mentors where email=$1", [
        email,
    ]);
    if (result_g) {
        return res.json({ id: result_g.rows[0].id, user: "graduates"});
    } else if (result_m) {
        return res.json({ id: result_m.rows[0].id, user: "mentors" });
    } else {
        return res.json("email isn't found");
    }
} catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err, "server error");
}
});
```

However, I keep getting an error message "Unhandled promise rejection warning"
It isn't just a warning because I tried it using postman and the request doesn't work. I assume the error comes from the result_g and result_m or the if conditions but I cannot identify where exactly the problem is . I would really appreciate if someone explains why this isnt allowed in node/express. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: #1 Is you catch executing? Print the err. #2 print the result of query 1 and 2 to detect if there are errors. #3 Do the same in your final if else if to detect. Tell us the result of your logs

Comment: @Bravo it is coming from node.

Comment: OK - but it's not coming from that piece of code - since it's "guarded" by try/catch with no throw in the catch - something else is the problem

Comment: unless `const { email } = req.params;` is throwing of course - i.e if `req.params` is `null`, or `undefined` - put `const { email } = req.params;` inside the `try` - see if it resolves at least that unhandled rejection

Comment: What version of node do you have? (`node -v` to check). That error output looks like it may be from an older version of node, when unhandled promise rejections were logged with less detail.

Comment: @Bravo I am not sure what you mean by this piece of code didnt throw the error. const { email } = req.params works fine as I tried it separately for the two tables. The problem arises when I used two pool.queries and the if blocks.

Comment: does the `catch` get invoked?

Comment: I never mentioned the version ... does the catch get invoked?

Comment: @Bravo no the catch doesnt get invoked.

Comment: so, if you just remove say the `result_m =` and the `else if (result_m)` - no problem?

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting a clear stack trace in the error output in node 14. You can try listening to the `unhandledRejection` event on `process` and logging `error.stack` there to see the stack trace. I don't think this error is from the code you showed.

Comment: by the way, personally, I'd run the `result_g` query, return if there's success, otherwise run the `result_m` query ... no need to run that if the first gets a result

Comment: @JRichardsz the catch doesn't execute. The first if block works (as I put graduates and mentors in quotes now) but nothing past that executes. Meaning if an email isnt in the graduate table it throws the same error I posted in my question.

Comment: Put a `console.log("in catch block", err)` as the first line inside the `catch` block to see if you're getting there just in case, the `res.send()` itself in the catch block is throwing.

Comment: @jfriend00 just did that and it doesnt execute.

Comment: so, it's not the fact that you have two requests? you said it works separately for the two tables

Comment: @Bravo I dont know for sure if having two queries is the reason for the error. The endpoint works for either of the two queries and it also works when the first query succeeds i.e. in the above code when the email is found in the graduate's table it gives the right response. When it fails it throws the rejection warning.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few errors in this code. Unfortunately, they combine to make the Node.js error message really hard to read. But luckily, they're all easy fixes! Let's look identify them individually first, then pull them all together to explain the error.

- **We can't check whether rows were returned using `if (result)`**. The [mysql `query`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries) function returns a `ResultSet`, which will always be truthy. (`if (result_g.rows)` doesn't work either – an [empty array is truthy in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).)

  So the `if (result_g)` in your code always executes. The next line includes `result_g.rows[0].i`. Which leads to...
- **Accessing a property on `undefined` raises an exception**. Even though our result set is empty – there are no matching graduates – we run `return res.json({ id: result_g.rows[0].id, user: "graduates"})`.

  - `result_g.rows` is an empty array `[]`.
  - `result_g.rows[0]` returns `undefined`.
  - `result_g.rows[0]` raises a `TypeError` ("undefined is not an object").

  That error's caught by the `catch` block, which brings us to the final problem.
- **The response syntax in the try/catch is incorrect**. You try to send an error response via `return res.status(500).send(err, "server error")`, but [`send()` takes only one parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send). (Older versions of Express [have a 2-argument `send()` function](https://expressjs.com/en/3x/api.html#res.send), but I don't think they support receiving an exception either.)

  This raises another exception from within your `catch` block. And that gives the error you see on your console: we threw an error within the async function of your `router.post` definition.

---

Fortunately, we can fix these with some small edits:

```
  try {
      const result_g = await pool.query(
          "select *  from graduates where email=$1",
          [email]
      );
      const result_m = await pool.query("select *  from mentors where email=$1", [
          email,
      ]);
-     if (result_g) {
+     if (result_g.rows.length > 0) {
          return res.json({ id: result_g.rows[0].id, user: "graduates"});
-     } else if (result_m) {
+     } else if (result_m.rows.length > 0) {
          return res.json({ id: result_m.rows[0].id, user: "mentors" });
      } else {
          return res.json("email isn't found");
      }
  } catch (err) {
-      return res.status(500).send(err, "server error");
+      return res.status(500).send("server error");
  }
```